# .net standard 2.0 and 4.7 of framework support

Tags: .net-core, .net-standard, .net-framework-version

Looking here https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions.md
Which shows support for framework versions e.g 4.6.1 supports 2.0 standard.
My question is where is 4.6.2 and 4.7 frameworks here?
Am I missing something obvious, can't understand why 4.7 not in list

Comment: I don't understand your question.  2.0 is the latest standard, and it is supported as of 4.6.1.  Higher versions still support 2.0.

Comment: In the table in the link there is no mention of 4.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table shows the **minimum** versions supporting the version of .NET Standard. Since .NET Standard 2.0 is supported by .NET Framework 4.6.1, this means that 4.6.2, 4.7, 4.7.1 and those that will follow also support it.